# Map automation using ArcPy with ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, layers, pdf

I wrote Python code with the ArcPy library.

The main purpose of script is to load a locally stored shapefile, assign it a style, labels, and then use a layout template to automate map generation.

What I can’t do is refresh the layout model view on the scope of the file I imported.

Here’s the script I created:

```
import arcpy 
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

shp2 = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)

p = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject(r"C:\Users\user\Documents\ArcGIS\Projects\Mon projet87\Mon projet87.aprx")

map = p.listMaps("Carte")[0]

shp1=map.listLayers()[0]

arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management(shp2, shp1)

Layout = p.listLayouts()[1]

mf = Layout.listElements('MAPFRAME_ELEMENT')[0]

Layout.exportToPDF(r"F:.....")
```

Comment: If I have understood what you said `shp2` is a path to a shapefile? You then apply the symbology of `shp1` to it which is the first layer in a map called Carte. But you have not added to `shp2` to the map so that's why its not in the layout.

Comment: with which command I can add it in the map ? and how I can zoom in on the extent of shp2 ? Thanks

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications and/or additional information relevant to your questions.

Comment: Your code is pretty confusing. If you make a distinction between *sources* (the shapefiles) and *layers* (the rendering  properties) in your code, you might get less tangled. You should also conform to [PEP8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/) naming conventions (only use `FirstCapital` for classes, `lowercase` for variables) to make code code clearer (change `Layout` to `layout`). Also spaces in folder names are an invitation to disaster -- use underscores instead.

Comment: Please dont do this: `map = p.listMaps("Carte")[0]`  -- *map* is a Python thing. It could have unintended consequences. The same as using reserved words in a DB for field names.

Comment: Have you tried reading the help file and searching for something like "arcpy add layer to map"? Then explore the map object?